# Why vesperascit instead of vesperescit?

Tags: verbs, morphology, derivation, vowel

I was recently working on a little translation project and my intuition and memory suggested that "evening comes" is *vesperescit*.
Checking dictionaries corrected me: it is *vesperascit* instead.
Why is that?
Should I have been able to guess that there is an *-a-* instead of an *-e-* before the incohative *-sc-*?

More generally, what determines the vowel before the incohative *-sc-*?
My understanding was that if no vowel is already there (assuming my verb comes from *vesper* instead of *vespera*), one should expect an *-e-*.
There is clearly a hole in my intuition when it comes to the incohative derivatives.

Comment: Will include this in a more complete answer I haven’t the time to write now: for now, let me cite from _[S. Isidori, Hispalensis episcopi... Opera omnia, denuo correcta et aucta:](https://books.google.it/books?id=fMnyEyLo1XQC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22vesperescit%22&source=bl&ots=odB5Fm6slQ&sig=uzGkMILBNHoew2nDNTdLfFiIW_s&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5uaeykMjaAhXJaRQKHb0gCT4Q6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=%22vesperescit%22&f=false) 608: inter __Vesperescit__ et __Vesperascit:__ __vesperescit,__ id est sero fit, __vesperascit,__ sol ad occasum declinat._

Comment: @Dario That sounds very promising! I look forward to a comparison of the two verbs.

Comment: I've just remembered *obliviscor.*

Comment: @Hugh It would be unfortunate for that verb to go to oblivion.

Answer (score 3):

vesper (m.) occurs both as an -o stem (gen. vesperi) and as a consonant stem (gen. vesperis), and then there is the -ā stem vespera (fem.) with the same meaning. The verb vesperasco is formed from the latter.